# Exclude certain results from in condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

```
Table 1
Id data1  data1
1  'ff'   'ffe'
2  'r'    '3'
3  'df'   'er'

Table 2
Id   WFID  data1   data2
1    12    'd'     'e'
1    13    '3'     '4f'
1    15    'e'     'dd'
2    12    'f'     'ee'
3    17    'd'     'f'
```

Now what I need is to join the two tables and get the data when only WFID is 12 or 17 for the record and 12 or 17 only. In this case Id number 1 has 12 but it also has 13 and 15 so it's excluded. Id number 2 and 3 are included because they have just 12 or 17.

I used the below query but it is also giving me data with id 1. Can someone please tell me what I can use to fix this.

```
select * from Table1
where Exists (select distinct ID from Table2 where 
    Table1.ID = Table2.ID and
    WFID in (12,17))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all IDs where only any of the values 12 & 17 exist, but no other value.

Use *conditional aggregation*:

```
select * from Table1
where ID in  
 (
   select ID 
   from Table2
   group by ID
   having sum(case when WFID in (12,17) then 1 else -1000 end) > 0
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an `NOT EXISTS` and a `NOT IN`. Also, there's no need to use a `DISTINCT` in a subquery being referenced in an `EXISTS`. You don't even need to actually reference a column in truth.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from dbo.Table2 T2
                  WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
                    AND WFID NOT IN (12,17));
```